# How to use CLASSPATH / PATH?

Tags: java, classpath

To begin with, I'm not entirely sure this is the correct question. Basically, my end goal is to produce a program that can manipulate a set of .docx files to have small changes to each of them. It seemed to me that docx4j was the best way to complete this goal. However, I've never used a library outside of the provided one. I began by attempting to decipher all the information provided in the manual, and it began by telling me I need SLF4J in order to let me use docx4j.

The SLF4J manual told me to 
"add the file slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar to your class path."
as well as the file 
"slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar"

I proceeded to go to System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables and I found "Path" under System variables. It seemed to me that this was the correct "class path", so I added to the end of it 
C:\Users\diego_000\Desktop\slf4j-1.7.7\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\diego_000\Desktop\slf4j-1.7.7\slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar;
This seemed to be what the manual told me to do and I was confident of the Hello World program (provided by their website) running successfully.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
    logger.info("Hello World");
  }
}
```

On compilation, I'm thrown the following errors:

```
Compilation completed.  The following files were not compiled:
4 errors found:
File: C:\Users\diego_000\Desktop\Program\HelloWorld.java  [line: 1]
Error: package org.slf4j does not exist
File: C:\Users\diego_000\Desktop\Program\HelloWorld.java  [line: 2]
Error: package org.slf4j does not exist
File: C:\Users\diego_000\Desktop\Program\HelloWorld.java  [line: 6]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class HelloWorld
File: C:\Users\diego_000\Desktop\Program\HelloWorld.java  [line: 6]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable LoggerFactory
  location: class HelloWorld
```

From this, I gather I've done something wrong. I'm fairly certain I know the pseudo logic behind the program I want to write, but I'm not really sure how to get to the point of writing it. I haven't done any research past the point I'm at, but if someone could go beyond just this question and walk me through the steps of getting to the writing code point, I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you everyone for answering, especially JasonPlutext, I ended up using Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, the PATH is for executables... Check out the CLASSPATH section at the end.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Okay, so I went to the environment variables section and added a "CLASSPATH" variable, with the two paths above that I mentioned and got the same errors, what am i missing?

Comment: Easiest to use an IDE and Maven.  Try http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2011/10/hello-maven-central/

Comment: You're not running `javac` in Cygwin or similar are you? Be aware that Windows uses semi-colons as path separators but UN*X-style environments use colons.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath), the top answer shows how to set jar files as part of the classpath.
for javac (compiler version) the format is similar

```
java -cp "Test.jar;lib/*" my.package.MainClass

javac -classpath .:/home/avh/classes:/usr/local/java/classes ...
javac -cp .:/home/avh/classes:/usr/local/java/classes ...
```

Please note that on linux/unix the path separator is : , on windows the quoted string and ; is usually the way to go.